# Help adding color to an image texture

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, image

I have done much texturing so bare with me... Im making a car and wanted to texture the brake lights with an image like this (pic 1).  I don't want to  project the image, I want to use this as an image texture but with the same colour... how would I go about doing this?

Ive started with a glass material and image texture over that (pic 2) which works fine but its B&W.

Pic 3 has the color but no glass look to it

And pic 4 just has the glass over it.  I was looking for a the texture of pic 1 and with picture 2 colour.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry cegaton, I was a bit too vague, I've attached my node set up

Comment: Bump... anyone?